# How to export an array with 3 paramaters to json file?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I would like to export datas to a json file. It would be a simple registration page.
I have the datas, but I can not export them, because I have 3 parameters:

-Username
-Email
-Password

```
   <html>
    <body marginleft="auto" marginright="auto" marginwidth="500px" >
      <form method="post">
        Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <br>
        Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <br>
        Password:
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <br>

       <?php
        $allDatas = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
        $usernames = array();
        $passwords = array();
        $emails = array();

        foreach ($allDatas as $data) {
            array_push($usernames, $data[0]);
        }
        foreach ($allDatas as $data) {
            array_push($passwords, $data[1]);
        }
        foreach ($allDatas as $data) {
            array_push($emails, $data[2]);
        }

        if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['username'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $foundedUser = false;

            foreach ($usernames as $key => $value) {
                if ($value == $username) {
                    echo "Error: Username exsists;";
                }
            }
            foreach ($emails as $key => $value) {
                if ($value == $email) {
                    echo "Error: Email registered;";
                }
            }

            array_push($usernames, $username);
            array_push($passwords, $password);
            array_push($emails, $email);

            unset($allDatas);
            $allDatas = array();
            ????
            }
        }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Registration">
        <br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you for the answers!!

Comment: simple: just create a new array with `$usernames`, `$passwords` and `$emails`, after that json_encode them. You will get an json with `Username -Email -Password`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create separate `$usernames`, `$emails`, and `$passwords` arrays. You can simply loop through `$allData` to search for existing entries that match the registration.

Second, you need to set `$founduser` when you find a match, and check that before adding the new user.

Third, you should add the new user to `$allData`, then write that out to the file as JSON.

```
  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $allDatas = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $foundedUser = false;

        foreach ($allDatas as $value) {
            if ($value[0] == $username) {
                echo "Error: Username exsists;";
                $foundUser = true;
                break;
            } elseif ($value[2] == $email) {
                echo "Error: Email registered;";
                $foundUser = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$foundUser) {
            $allDatas[] = array($username, $email, $password);
            file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($allDatas));
        }

        unset($allDatas);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: As per OP's requirement i just give him the way how can he did this. But you the one who make up all the essentials things what he need to do, thanks. You are Great...

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create a json string from $usernames, $passwords and $emails these arrays. You need to create a new array and insert these arrays into that new array, after that just use `json_encode` you will get a new json string.

Outside your if condition, you have to do these.

You have these:

```
array_push($usernames, $username);
array_push($passwords, $password);
array_push($emails, $email);
```

Do this:

```
$newArr = array();
$newArr[] = $username;
$newArr[] = $passwords;
$newArr[] = $emails;

$newstring = json_encode($newArr);
```

Let me know you are helpful or not.

Comment: This will lose all the other users in the JSON file. The new user needs to be added to that array, not replace it.

Comment: As per OP's requirement i just give him the way how can he did this. But you the one who make up all the essentials things what he need to do, thanks. You are Great...